# Check if a method with parameters has arguments?

Tags: java, parameters, arguments

I have my method

```
public static boolean method(int[] v, int n) throws IllegalArgumentException
{
   //throw Exception if the method has < 1 Argument
}
```

And I want to check that when I call my method if it has any arguments. Is it possible to do this?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   try
   {
   method(); //call method without any arguments
   }catch(Exception e)
   {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The code won't compile, that is your check.

Comment: Shouldn't it not even compile if you are calling a method while passing it the wrong number of parameters?

Comment: Can you please explain your question, do you want to check the number of arguments before calling it? or you want to call the method without providing the parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible in java.
What you could do instead is creating an other method with the same name which does not need any parameters. In there you can invoke the other method with the parameters plus your stuff

Comment: It is possible to check the parameters of the method. Study Java Reflection.

Comment: @RehanJaved Not like this; that's not the sort of thing that makes sense.  This is resolved at compile time; reflection is a runtime thing.

Comment: Actually he does not mean he only wrote "method()", read his statement, he said "And I want to check that when I call my method if it has any arguments. Is it possible to do this?" He means he want to check in the code that it has any argument while calling or not.

Comment: I think because of the ' //throw Exception if the method has < 1 Argument' comment that he miswrote his question and instead tries to invoke the method both with and without parameters @RehanJaved

Comment: By the way, it will be better, if he explain the issue more thoroughly.